# is there any solution for MYSQL Error Code: 1442?

Tags: mysql, sql

my code is very long so i'm gonna make it simple.
i have the following:

```
table1 --> have a trigger on insert (call function1 to insert into table2)
table2 --> have a trigger on insert (call function2)

function2()
update table1 depending on a query that table1 is related to.
```

and i get error can't update table table1 in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this....

so is there any solution or workaround for this...

Comment: Are you saying the trigger on table2 inserts records in to table1?

Comment: no, it is running a function that updates table1

Comment: When the actual code is large (really, anytime you're posting code), you can always produce a [minimal sample case](http://sscce.org/) instead of a vague diagram.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to understand about triggers is they are part of the transaction.

So Insert Table 1, triggers insert table 2 which updates table1, could cause  the original insert to bump into itself. Not done triggers with MySQl, in theory this could be okay, if it's attemting to update the record originally inserted, which hasn't actually been committed yet....

Try and avoid the situation is the usual best advice, however if you can't, an intermediate table might work (insert into that and have it trigger changes to Table1 and 2), or better still, instead of using a direct insert , used a stored procedure and have it update tables 1 & 2 cummulativley.

e.g. instead on insert Table1=A, which causes Table2=B which Causes Table1(A) to become C
and SP which looks up what B would do to A and insert that in A(c) and the corresponding record in B.

Triggers are great, but don't go mad with them.

Comment: well i like the idea of the intermediate table but i think if i inserted the values that is need to be updated in that table and create a trigger on it to update table1, the update is still part of the transaction and it will be the same problem.

Comment: Has to be enough data / logic in the intermediate to 'work' out what should go in Table1 and 2. So insert into intermediate triggers insert into teh deopendant tables they donl't trigger each other. I prefer the sp solution myself, it's more in your face, and you can set up permissions so only the SP can insert into either table, though that could cause extra work if teh logic is or gets more complex.